# Make an array add +1 to index if a specific condition is met in swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I am new to new to programming in general, but started with Swift
Could not find my answer searching google, also looked at apple documentation, but I was getting nowhere.
So what I am trying to do, is to make an array display the next item in it when a specific condition is met, for example it was and index 0 but now it has to show the one that was at index 1; if it where 2, to show the one at index 3, and so on.

```
var location = [
    "City Center right",
    "City Center left",
    "City District right",
    "City District left",
    "Periphery right",
    "Periphery left"]

var arrivingCity = [location[0], location[2], location[4]]

var arrivingLeft = true

if arrivingLeft == true {    
    arrivingCity = // here is should change the index +1 so it will show as// [location[1], location[3], location[5]]
}
```

Comment: `let offset = arrivingLeft ? 1 : 0)`, `let arrivingCity = [location[0 + offset], location[2 + offset], location[4 + offset]]`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

For an extensible solution, you should maintain indexes of locations.

```swift
var location = [
    "City Center right",
    "City Center left",
    "City District right",
    "City District left",
    "Periphery right",
    "Periphery left"]


// Instead of storing locations store its indexes
var arrivingCityIndexes = [0, 2, 4]

var arrivingLeft = true

if arrivingLeft == true {   
     // Increment each index by one to move to the next city
    arrivingCityIndexes = arrivingCityIndexes.map { $0 + 1 }
}

// When required, map the `arrivingCityIndexes` array to an array of arriving city names
let arrivingCity = arrivingCityIndexes.map { location[$0] }
```